# Best method of On-page authorization Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a page: on that page if the `usertype` is `admin`, he/she can view (and search through) all records however if the `usertype` is `standard user` he/she can only view and search his/her own records.

Would would `Zend Framework` suggest as `best practice`. I am using `Zend ACL` at the moment, so if I seperate into actions then I have to change the menus to point to the different `actions` depending on the `usertype in session`.

I could use the method of in the `controller checking the usertype` and making the relevant changes in the action and view.

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A famous ACL example:
>
> In a Blog controller, there are publishAcion(), viewAction(),
>   editAction(), deleteAction().
>
> For unregistered user, we restrict his access to publish, edit, and delete post.
>
> So, your question is similar with this use case: registered
>   user can edit his own post while administrator can edit all the posts, and ideally to use the same editAction().

To return different result based on user's role is more of your business logic. Good news is you don't have to write multiple actions. Actually it is probably not a bad decision, because you will be separating your application into two sections: front-end and admin-panel. Does it sound familiar?

There are three approaches:

**Controller Approach**

```
public function viewAction(){

    $record = new Model_Record();

    switch (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getRole()){
        case 'admin':
            $recordResult = $record->getAllRecords(); break;
        case 'standard user':
            $recordResult = $record->getRecordsByUserId(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getId()); break;
}
```

This is logical by using two actions getAllRecords() and getRecordsByUserId() based on role. You can keep the simplicity of your model actions.

**Action Helper Approach**

This one extends above approach further. Sometimes you will have to use **Controller Approach** multiple times in different controllers. To reduce duplicate code (always the top 1 best practice of all), write a controller action helper: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.writingyourown)

**/library/Application/Controller/Action/Helper/GetRecordsBasedOnRole.php**

```
class Application_Controller_Action_Helper_GetRecordsBasedOnRole extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{

    public function direct()
    {

        $record = new Model_Record();
        $recordResult = array();

        switch (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getRole()){
            case 'admin':
            $recordResult = $record->getAllRecords(); break;
        case 'standard user':
            $recordResult = $record->getRecordsByUserId(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getId()); break;

        return $recordResult;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to tell Zend where it is, add this line to **Application.ini**:

> resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.Application_Controller_Action_Helper = "Application/Controller/Action/Helper/"

Then you can use it in every controller simply with one line of code:

```
$recordResult = $this->_helper->getRecordsBasedOnRole();
```

**Model Approach**

```
function getRecordsBasedOnRole(){

    $select = "SELECT * FROM recordTable";

    if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getRole() != 'admin'){
        $select .= " WHERE id = " . Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getId();
    }
    ...
}
```

Through this approach, you will be able to use getRecordsBasedOnRole() in all your controllers to get data based on user's role.

```
$record = new Model_Record();
$recordResult = $record->getRecordsBasedOnRole()
```

**A little sugar**

If you prefer Action Helper Approach. You probably haven't read this good article talks about action stack performance issue: http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/

However, it's also not a good practice to put Zend_Auth in your model to check user's role because this adds extra memory usage.

Every implementation in IT industry is a trade off. In this case maybe there is no perfect solution, but Model solution is 
better. Because storage is cheap nowadays.